# Alterar senha do GIT no Windows

Tags: git, cmd

Uso o *git* no *Windows* e estou precisando saber como alterar a senha dele através do *CMD*. Toda vez que tento fazer um `git push`, ele dá o erro abaixo e preciso digitar o login e a 'nova' senha

> ```
> fatal: HttpRequestException encountered. Ocorreu um erro ao enviar
> a solicitação. Username for 'https://github.com':
> ```

Lembro de ter feito isso logo que instalei o *GIT* no windows, mas não sei como alterar a senha que já está gravada.

Comment: Nosso idioma é o portugues, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Já tentou `git config credential.helper store` ou ainda adicionar a senha no *remote origin* `https://username:password@github.com/jquery/jquery.git`?

Comment: Tentei usar git config credential.helper store mas acredito que esteja faltando alguma diretiva para salvar meu password

Answer (score 1):

Talvez sua senha esteja salva no gerenciador de credenciais do windows. Para confirmar, verifique se no arquivo `.gitconfig` em `C:/Users/SeuUsuario/`, a opção credential aparece como:

```
[credential]
helper = wincred
```

Se estiver assim, acesse o "Gerenciador de Credenciais" do Windows (digite na barra de busca, ao lado do logo do windows na barra inferior) e mude a sua senha por la.

Comment: Não tem isso no meu .gitconfig mas tem um arquivo .gitcredentials com meu username e coloquei a senha correta.

Agora está subindo sem pedir a senha, mas continua dando o erro "fatal: HttpRequestException encountered. Ocorreu um erro ao enviar"

Answer (score 0):

Tenta mudar as credenciais que estão salvas no windows: Painel de Controle -> Conta de Usuário -> Gerenciar Credencias do Windows -> Credencias genéricas: selecione a credencial do git e altere sua senha para a nova.